# Delay in ADAL UI full population

Tags: azure-active-directory

When we call acquireTokenWithResource ADAL API, there is consistently a delay of around 4-5 seconds where a white ADAL UI comes up (that has no spinner, just cancel button).  Is there a way to minimize this delay?

AzureAD

Comment: Since ADAL provided several version for the different language and platform, would you minding let us know what's the platform and adal were you developing?

Comment: ADAL 2.4.1
iOS 9.3.5